# Haar wavelets - Partial signal reconstruction

Tags: r, wavelet, haar-wavelet, dwt

I'm trying to approximate a time series/vector usind dwt. I can apply the full dwt and idwt reconstruction, but i don´t know how to reconstruct/approximate the original signal based on just a few coefficients (not all).

I tryed this:

```
library(wavelets)
x<-c(7, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 4, 6)
w <- dwt(x, filter="haar",n.levels = 3)
rec<-idwt(w)
```

I read about coefficient  truncation, but I don´t know how to do it.

What if I need an approximation based on ,lets say, 2 coefficients?

I'll appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

In between lines 3 and 4 you can do

```
str    (w)     # see what w looks like
w@W$W1 []  = 0 # set the 1st level detail coefficients to 0
```

then your `rec` will be

```
[1] 6 6 4 4 3 3 5 5
```

and that makes sense: without detail coefficients on the finest level the Haar transform returns the average of each pair of points, for both points.